# Function to adjust the EXCEL INDEX(MATCH())-function

Tags: excel, index-match

I'm looking for an EXCEL function to list ONLY the approved (YES) numbers of a table A, in another table B. I used  the `INDEX(MATCH())` function but it seems not to work. So in conclusion: Check the column of "approved by team" and if "Yes" fill in the connected number in that row or first column.

[image: Example tables with INDEX()]

I tried: `=INDEX(C7:E16;MATCH("Yes";E7:E16;0);1)` but now he returns some numbers double (see picture).

I think I figured out the reason why I get double numbers. He checks every row for a match with "Yes" until he finds a match. So if he finds no "Yes" in E9, he gives back the next "Yes" in E10. Then he checks E10 and finds a "Yes" so gives back the same number again. So in conclusion I need to intergrate a function which tells him to start with the cell below the next "Yes". That would fix the problem.

Comment: The FILTER() function is designed to do this.

Comment: You asked this earlier, won’t come back to it again.

Comment: @SolarMikeThis is correct. You gave me a very useful tip but the link you send with the possible solution was too complex to understand for me. I told you this, so after still not solving the problem I have to post the question again but with the details I already adjusted. But still thx for your help earlier